# A yellow triangle Warning sign is showing in the corner of code line

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting

I am hosting a website using NODEJS and EXPRESS. but while editing the app.js file in cpanel editor a yellow sign icon is showing in front of code with some irrelevant suggestions. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXxRG.png) for clarity of question. Server is showing error 503 which means unavailable. There is no problem in code as it is smoothly working in localhost, But in Cpanel!?

```js
const http = require('http');
const port = process.env.PORT;

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const con = require('./model/user');

const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    con.connect(function(error){
        if (error) throw error;
        
        var sql = "INSERT INTO customers(username, password) Values('"+username+"','"+password+"')";
        con.query(sql,function(error, result){
            if (error) throw error; 
            res.send('registration succesfully');
        });
    });
    
    res.json({ status: 'ok'})
});

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log('Server')
})
```

i was expecting that my server will run as it was running with this code

```
const http = require('http');
const port = process.env.PORT;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    
});
```